# How to convert "jar" to Linux executable file?

Tags: java, linux, jar, executable-jar

I know how to convert "jar" to windows executable file(.exe). But I want to know how to convert "jar" to Linux executable file(.?). I have searched google but didn't get exact answer what i want, help to do this.

Comment: What do you mean by "Linux execrable file?"

Comment: You can execute the `jar` file by shell command just like `.sh` file in linux or `.bat` file in windows.

Comment: I know how to run "jar" file in Linux, But I need to convert it to (.sh) linux application file. Like (.exe) file in windows

Comment: Have you tried:
`sudo chmod +x myFile.jar`

Comment: Why not just use a script (.sh) that triggers the jar-file, if you have to mask the application? Why can't you use the `java -jar <file>` command anyway?

Comment: I have to hide "jar" file from the user

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an executable jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258159/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file)

Comment: I have got exact answer from the following Link [Converted Jar file to Linux executable file using gcj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429976/how-to-convert-a-java-or-a-jar-file-into-a-linux-executable-file-without-a)

Comment: As of Java 14, the JDK comes with [jpackage](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/jpackage/basic-packaging.html). See also the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file).

Answer (score 32):

> I want to know how to convert "jar" to Linux executable file(.?).

Linux does not have executable files the same way that Windows does. In Linux we have binaries and scripts. Scripts are ran with an interpreter; languages like Ruby and Python. Binaries are files of compiled code, they can be libraries or entire programs. Both binaries and scripts can be executable.

To make a program executable in Linux, type this into the command
line.

```
$ chmod +x myProgram
```

Alternatively you can open file preferences and set executable in the
permissions section.

Since Linux does not have `.exe` files or an analogue, we'll have to work something else out. Linux and other Unix like Operating system have a shell called bash; often called the command line or terminal in reference to Linux and Mac. We want to create a file that can be run as our entire program, instead of having to call `$ java -jar myProgram.jar`. To tell bash to start a script environment for a file we use a *hashbang*. This is the first line of the file which instructs bash were to look for the interpreter to send the rest of the file to. For a bash script, like Batch Script on Windows, we would start the file with `#!/bin/bash`. The path after the `#!` (hashbang) tells bash were to look for the interpreter. For a `.jar` make the hashbang `#!/usr/bin/java -jar` and then cat the `.jar` to the file with the hashbang. This can be done all from the terminal in Linux.

Create a file with the java jar hashbang.

```sh
$ echo '#!/usr/bin/java -jar' > myBin
```

We have written the hashbang as a string to the new file myBin.

Write the jar to the file.

```sh
$ cat my.jar >> myBin
```

The `>>` appends the jar to the receiving file.

This will create a file that has the bash hashbang and the jar appended to it. Next set `myBin` to executable and try to run the program.

```sh
$ chmod +x myBin
$ ./myBin
```

Answer (score 8):

Create a sh wrapper file with following content and make it executable:

```
#!/bin/bash

java -jar <your-jar>
```

Optionally add some vm arguments.

Perhaps there are some tools that could generate such a file, but is is little effort to do it manually I reckon.

Comment: Though the top answer is a little more thorough, it's also somewhat pedantic, correspondingly confusing to some and quite off-topic. This answer is the most accurate and immediately useful. I would only clarify by enhancing the actual command thus: "java -jar <full-jar-path> $*" That allows the script to work from any generic bin directory and conveys any arguments to the JAR for specific handling.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [packr](https://github.com/libgdx/packr) tool. It will help you create a native Linux executable file from your Java application.

Answer (score 1):

You can always run a jar file by doing `java -jar myFile.jar`.

However, to make the jar file itself executable, you need to set the executable bit, as the message hints. `chmod +x /path/to/your/file/myFile.jar` will accomplish this.

After that you can do `./myFile.jar` to run it.

`man chmod` will provide you with information about how chmod works.

Source: [How can I make a .jar file executable?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270172/how-can-i-make-a-jar-file-executable)  on AskUbuntu. Answer by [Gary](https://askubuntu.com/users/129717/gary)

Comment: It doesn't work, at least on Ubuntu. Gives error like `cannot execute binary file: Exec format error` even if given the execute permission.

Answer (score 0):

While making a shell script works, it sort of seems a bit like overkill for most situations.  Why not just use an alias and throw it in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_aliases` file? Like so:

```
alias whatever='java -jar /path/to/whatever.jar'
```

(Since my solution didn't come up as an answer here, my "why" is a somewhat genuine question: Is there some hidden hazard or feature I'm missing? Or is it more of a matter of adhering to the strictest interpretation of the OP's question?)

Answer (score 0):

Probably what is more apt and exact in this case is to create a Desktop Configuration File.

Answer (score 0):

A very late answer but maybe someone will need it!

To make a jar file "executable" on Linux you need to open file Properities and in General section --> Open With --> click Change and add "java -jar" under Application Preference Order and set the Program executable in the permissions section.